# SQL Error Missing Right Parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am new to SQL and running this on command prompt with Orcale 11g installed

```
CREATE table Transaction(
Transaction_Id number PRIMARY KEY,
Account_No number FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Account_creation(Account_No),
Transaction_Date date,
Amount number,
Transaction_type varchar2(5) CHECK( Transaction_type=’C’ OR Transaction_type=’D’),
Current_Balance number,
Branch_code varchar2(10) );
```

I get the error907 at line 4 saying missing right parenthesis
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you're missing a right parenthesis

Comment: @adaam could you point out where exactly I'm missing a parenthesis

Answer (score 1):

If this line is really correct:

```
Transaction_type varchar2(5) CHECK( Transaction_type=’C’ OR Transaction_type=’D’),
```

Then you have the wrong single quotes in the line.  Try this:

```
Transaction_type varchar2(5) CHECK( Transaction_type = 'C' OR Transaction_type = 'D'),
```

Or, better yet:

```
Transaction_type varchar2(5) CHECK( Transaction_type in ('C', 'D')),
```

Comment: I tried both the methods I'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE table Transaction(
Transaction_Id number PRIMARY KEY,
Account_No number,
Transaction_Date date,
Amount number,  
Transaction_type varchar2(5) CHECK( Transaction_type=’C’ OR Transaction_type=’D’),
Current_Balance number,
Branch_code varchar2(10), 
FOREIGN KEY (Account_No) REFERENCES Account_creation(Account_No)
);
```